Can someone help me find the error in my code?
My content won't rest inside my background image properly. I need it to be centered with one another. It's just not happening. The first image is the expectation and the other is mine. Can anyone cross check my code and help provide a solution?



expectation
mine









<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Background Video</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="hero">
            <video autoplay loop muted plays-inline >
                <source src="assets/4763824-uhd_3840_2160_24fps.mp4" />
            </video>
        </section>
        <section class="content">
            <h1>Journey</h1>
            <a href=" ">Explore</a>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.hero {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(12, 3, 51, 0.3), rgba(12, 3, 51, 0.3));
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 5%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.content {
    text-align: center;
   
}

.content h1 {
    font-size: 160px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 600;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.content h1:hover {
    -webkit-text-stroke: 2px white;
    color: transparent;
}

.content a {
   text-decoration: none;
   display: inline-block;
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 24px;
   border: 2px solid white;
   padding: 14px 50px;
   margin-top: 20px;
   transition: 0.5s;
}

.content a:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

.back-video {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
   .back-video {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
   }
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
    .back-video {
     width: auto;
     height: 100%;
    }
 }

I tried changing the position and display of the hero class but it did nothing.
